# why xml file does not aligned properly after append the string in beginning and end of the file using java?

Tags: java, xml, file, dom

I have added the string in beginning and end of the XML File.but the alignment is not proper after getting the result.

My XML File:

```
        import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Reader;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.w3c.dom.Text;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

import com.google.common.io.Resources;

import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class ModifyXMLFile {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        try {
            // Point the file directory path here
            String directory = "C:\\Users\\n444479\\Desktop\\SA";
            int test = new File("C:\\Users\\n444479\\Desktop\\SA").listFiles().length;
            File[] files = new File(directory).listFiles();

            // Loop the file to run all the XML files
            for (int j = 0; j < test; j++) {
                System.out.println(files[j]);

                String filepathext = files[j].toString();

                DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepathext);

                /*
                // XML file update starts here

                // 1.Add the attribute element with value between the two XML
                // Child elements



                 NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("dummySegmentOne");
                 Text a = doc.createTextNode("value"); Element p =
                 doc.createElement("newNode"); p.appendChild(a);
                 nodes.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(p, nodes.item(0));


                // 2.Add the attribute element without value between the two XML
                // Child elements


                 NodeList nodesa =
                 doc.getElementsByTagName("customerLevelRegDocs"); Element q =
                 doc.createElement("dummySegmentOne");
                 nodesa.item(0).getParentNode().insertBefore(q,
                 nodesa.item(0));


                // 3.Rename the element in parent and child both using the JAXP
                // Parser
                */
                // XSLT File:

                String xsltResource = "C:\\Users\\n444479\\Desktop\\AB\\test.xml";

                StringWriter xmlResultResource = new StringWriter();

                Transformer xmlTransformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer(
                                new StreamSource(new File(xsltResource)));
                xmlTransformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File(filepathext)),new StreamResult(xmlResultResource));

                // XML file update end here

                // write the content into XML file
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory
                        .newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new String(filepathext));
                transformer.transform(source, result);
                transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "2");
                // Successful output once get it "Done"
                String output = xmlResultResource.getBuffer().toString();
                // Writing the transformed XML to a file
                FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filepathext);
                fileWriter.write(output);
                fileWriter.close();

                System.out.println("Done");

            }
        }
        // Exception handling
        catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Once the program executed the string get appended properly but the XML File alignment changed.

The output i am getting as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>{% from lxml import etree %}{% from StringIO import StringIO %}{% set tree = parse_xml(request_text) %}{% set namespaces = {'soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',  'wbs': 'http://xml.ama.com/ws/2009/01/WBS_Session-2.0.xsd'}%}<soap:Envelope xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Header><Session><SessionId>{{tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SessionId', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text}}</SessionId><SequenceNumber>{{int(tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SequenceNumber', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)+1}}</SequenceNumber><SecurityToken>{{tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SecurityToken', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text}}</SecurityToken></Session></soap:Header><soap:Body><reRoot><reNode> world</reNode></reRoot></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

why the file not getting appeneded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [DataInputStream.readLine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInput.html#readLine()) discards the newline character. So, you'll have to append it yourself.

Moreover:
Take in account that the resulting XML is incorrect, because the original XML header turns out to be included in one node. The header (if present) must stay always before the root node.

To properly transform your input XML to a SOAP, I recommend you two alternatives:

- Either transform it through an **XSL** stylesheet.
- Or either build the resulting XML with **DOM** and include the source XML as one child node. Then, when serializing the whole document, you may specify indentation parameters.

**Update**

I suggest you this XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"/>

<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/">{% from lxml import etree %}{% from StringIO import StringIO %}{% set tree = parse_xml(request_text) %}{% set namespaces = {'soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',  'wbs': 'http://xml.ama.com/ws/2009/01/WBS_Session-2.0.xsd'}%}<soap:Envelope xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Session>
      <SessionId>{{tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SessionId', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text}}</SessionId>
      <SequenceNumber>{{int(tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SequenceNumber', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)+1}}</SequenceNumber>
      <SecurityToken>{{tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SecurityToken', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text}}</SecurityToken>
    </Session>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body><xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In other words: It creates a SOAP message with a fixed format, and sets the input xml as the contents of the `<soap:Body>` node.

And the transformation code:

```
private static void transform(org.w3c.dom.Document doc, java.io.InputStream inputXsl, java.io.OutputStream out)
    throws java.io.IOException,
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException,
    javax.xml.transform.TransformerException
{
    javax.xml.transform.Templates templates=javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTemplates(new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource(inputXsl));
    javax.xml.transform.Transformer transformer=templates.newTransformer();
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
    transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
    javax.xml.transform.Result result=new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(out);
    javax.xml.transform.Source source=new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(doc);
    if (doc.getInputEncoding() != null)
    {
        transformer.setOutputProperty("encoding", doc.getInputEncoding());
    }
    transformer.transform(source, result);
}
```

The whole result is re-indented by means of two causes:

- The `xsl:strip-space` in the XSL.
- The `indent` and `indent-amount` properties in the transformation.

Comment: I would like to do with the XSL Stylesheet,but XSL style sheet used to tranform the xml.i am not sure how to append the text using XSL Stylesheet.can i get an reference link?

Comment: I tried my level best using the xslt, but its able to append the file inside the xml file.but i want to append the text before and end of the xml file without change of xml alignment@Little Santi

Comment: where to update the xsl file path and the xml file path.here the private section not execute when simply mention the inside the code.@Little Santi

Comment: added the code as per your suggestion, but still not working.string is not appending to the top and end of the xml.@Little Santi

Comment: Fix: Change "new String(xsltResource)" by "new File(xsltResource)".

Comment: added the new File(xsltResource) in the code.but now the output came in single line.the code updated in the questions too.@Little Santi

Comment: @vidya No wonder. You called `transformer.transform` before `transformer.setProperty`. Better copy the static method `transform` exactly as I put in my answer.

Comment: sure i will take take this and how to mark your answer as right from my side. @Little Santi

Answer (score 0):

The below XSL Stylesheet will be formatting the xml properly

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="/">
{% from lxml import etree %}{% from StringIO import StringIO %}{% set tree = parse_xml(request_text) %}{% set namespaces = {'soapenv': 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/',  'wbs': 'http://xml.ama.com/ws/2009/01/WBS_Session-2.0.xsd'}%}
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xalan" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Header>
    <Session>
      <SessionId>{{tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SessionId', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text}}</SessionId>
      <SequenceNumber>{{int(tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SequenceNumber', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text)+1}}</SequenceNumber>
      <SecurityToken>{{tree.xpath('//soapenv:Header/wbs:Session/wbs:SecurityToken', namespaces=namespaces)[0].text}}</SecurityToken>
    </Session>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body><xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

@Little Santi thanks for helping me and getting understand things.