# how to append text in top and end of the .xml file using java?

Tags: java, file, parsing, io

I have an below xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reRoot>
<reNode> world</reNode>
</reRoot>
```

i would like to display my xml file after append the text as below,

```
Linesaddedbeforexml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <reRoot>
    <reNode> world</reNode>
    </reRoot>
Linesaddedafterxml
```

how to achieve this useing java,i tried Filewriter but the alignment not proper after writing it.,
need help in solution with sample logic code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer for the thread is posted on another thread which will be very helpful.

[how to append text in top and end of the .xml file using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39294618/why-xml-file-does-not-aligned-properly-after-append-the-string-in-beginning-and)

Answer (score -1):

After writing text with Filewritter you can do formatting of xml as below

```
public static String prettyFormat(String input) {
    Source xmlInput = new StreamSource(new StringReader(input));
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", 2);
        transformer.transform(xmlInput, new StreamResult(stringWriter));

        String pretty = stringWriter.toString();
        pretty = pretty.replace("\r\n", "\n");
        return pretty;              
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: where to mention the xml and xsl file path?@Jekin Kalariya

Comment: Vidya here parameter ofmethod will be your xml string